# xim not working in Chromium

Tags: chrome, xinput, input-method

For a long while now, I have been happily using the `xim` IME (so that I may use XCompose freely). And I have never had an issue (though some applications which do not sanely handle unicode have crashed on me before due to my use of Compose) with applications ignoring the IME.

However, it seems Chromium (just installed) completely ignores `xim`. I cannot use my Compose bindings at all.

I am using Arch Linux (which is just to say that the chromium package itself is very nearly vanilla—I do not believe this is an Arch issue, so I will leave the Arch tag off for now) and I have the following definitions in my `$HOME/.xinitrc` which have functioned properly for years:

```bsh
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim
```

TL;DR: Any idea why Chromium is ignoring `xim` or what I might do to get them to play nice?

Comment: I think it's something with the chromium itself. I recently had the same issue and couldn't find any way around it without changing input module (I installed and switched to `uim` which seems to be working without any configuration changes but I haven't really tested everything yet). I would really like to know what is different with those other input modules, I don't like installing and relying on 3rd-party stuff for something this basic. (xim worked for me for years as well)

Comment: Yes, I realize that this is probably a completely different issue with chromium. But I most of them had the same symptoms and affected only xim for some weird reason so my answer is probably still relevant.